# Harmony on Canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas

How we can color a canvas like this:

[image]

If pay attention,color cahnges relative to radius and it is not constant.I can not use shapes and gradiants.

Comment: Why can't you use gradients? It can be done using RadialGradient.

Comment: @Student Student see this question:http ://stackoverflow.com/q/2936803/1043882

Comment: @Student Student, did you achieve it, as I see you accepted my answer?

Comment: @Daler I achive that by using dynamic `shapedrawable` and others.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by using a combination of Gradients>Shape(ring)>United with LayerList. You have to spend some of your time achieving it.